# Recover Azure Durable function terminate uri

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

If I lost the terminate uri for an active Azure Durable function run, is there a way to recover it? I also don't have the instance id.

Comment: Is this that you want? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-http-api#terminate-instance

Comment: Thanks @BowmanZhu, but I didn't have the instance id either. Sorry, I should've specified that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you don't have the instance ID of the orchestration you can first call this API of your deployed function app:

```
GET /runtime/webhooks/durableTask/instances?
    taskHub={taskHub}
    &code={systemKey}
    &createdTimeFrom={timestamp}
    &createdTimeTo={timestamp}
    &runtimeStatus={runtimeStatus1,runtimeStatus2,...}
    &showInput=[true|false]
    &top={integer}
```

Where:

- The taskHub is the `hubName` value in the host.json (or a default, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-task-hubs?tabs=csharp).
- The code is the master (or system) key of the function app.
- The timestamps are in this format `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ` (e.g. 2020-02-01T00:00:00Z).
- The runtimeStatus is one or more of this enum:

  - Running = 0,
  - Completed = 1,
  - ContinuedAsNew = 2,
  - Failed = 3,
  - Canceled = 4,
  - Terminated = 5,
  - Pending = 6.

This returns a collection of orchestrations and one of these is the instance you want to terminate. Extract the instanceId and perform the following POST method to terminate the instance:

```
POST /runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/{instanceId}/terminate
    ?taskHub={taskHub}
    &connection={connectionName}
    &code={systemKey}
    &reason={text}
```

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-http-api#terminate-instance

Answer (score 1):

```
{
        "id": "d3b72dddefce4e758d92f4d411567177",
        "sendEventPostUri": "http://localhost:7071/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/d3b72dddefce4e758d92f4d411567177/raiseEvent/{eventName}?taskHub={taskHub}&connection={connection}&code={systemKey}",
        "statusQueryGetUri": "http://localhost:7071/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/d3b72dddefce4e758d92f4d411567177?taskHub={taskHub}&connection={connection}&code={systemKey}",
        "terminatePostUri": "http://localhost:7071/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/d3b72dddefce4e758d92f4d411567177/terminate?reason={text}&taskHub={taskHub}&connection={connection}&code={systemKey}"
    }
```

PS: get the ID from your Azure Table